# Calling two different functions from onKeyDown event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With below code I am trying to invoke two different function with onKeyDown event in ReactJS application.

But its not invoking any of those function. But, its working fine with one function call.

```
<input name="product_quantity"
       type="text"
       onKeyDown={ (event) => { 
           this.props.handleInputNumber; 
           this.handleQuantity; } } 
       value={ this.state.item.product_quantity }
       className="form-control"
/>
```

Comment: `(event) => { this.props.handleInputNumber(event); this.handleQuantity(event); }`

Comment: Are you sure you don't need the `event` param...?

Comment: No, you are correct,. without event it wont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing parentheses. Additionally you should either pass the `event` to at least one of those functions or remove it if it's unneeded.

E.g.
`event => this.props.handleInputNumber(event); this.handleQuantity(event);`

Comment: Just like in the other answer, this solution doesn't pass on the `event` parameter. Given that this is about handling a keypress, it seems to be useful to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td>
   <input name="product_quantity" type="text" 
          onKeyDown={(event) => { 
             this.props.handleInputNumber(); this.handleQuantity(); 
          }} 
          value={this.state.item.product_quantity} 
          className="form-control" /></td>
```

Comment: Sure, you aren't passing `event`.

Comment: @ChrisG , look at the question, you don't need to pass the event param in this case

Comment: @KentV, either use `event` in those functions, or remove it from the parameter. We don't know the definition of those 2 functions and if event is used.

Comment: @ChrisG , the question asks about the function invoking issue only and there's nothing about event object. Also there're cases you don't have to pass event param when you don't need it.

Comment: @KentV It's pretty likely that the OP previously had `onKey={this.props.handleInputNumber}` or something along those lines, which passes the parameters on. Replacing that with a two-calls version that suddenly *doesn't* pass on the parameter, especially given that one of them is a keypress handler, seems like trouble.

Comment: @KentV Also, Stack Overflow isn't primarily about answering individual questions as it is about building a repository or Qs and As that are helpful to other users who find them.

Comment: @ChrisG , It could've been better with comments on the questions asking about the event params. I don't feel I deserve a downvote

Comment: I feel you do, given that your answer is misleading and will lead to further issues down the line. Just like the other answer, which I also downvoted.